# "Have a difficult time doing" – is the action accomplished or not?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> I had a difficult time getting sleep.

Does the previous sentence mean "Though having a terrible time, I finally got sleep."?

What about another similar phrase, *have difficulty doing*: does it imply that the action was eventually done?

Comment: The adjective _difficult_ and the noun _difficulty_ on their own tell us nothing definite about whether an action was completed. Your example sentence, though, would be understood as _implying_ that the speaker eventually fell asleep ("got **to** sleep"). The phrase is incomplete: we _"get **to** sleep",_ we don't _"get sleep."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks for your correction and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If this were phrased:
"I had a difficult time getting to sleep."
or
"I had a difficult time falling asleep."

It does seem to imply that you finally did fall asleep.

If this were phrased:
"I had a difficult time getting any sleep."

That seems to imply that maybe you didn't really sleep, or else very little.

And the current sentence:
"I had a difficult time getting sleep."

As-is, it could mean that you did not really sleep much. Maybe just a little.